# When I stop AVAudioPlayer I get an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a `UIViewController`  which is playing music and `UITableViewController` which lists songs. I made that I leave `PlayViewController`, `AVAudioPlayer` will still be playing  a song. I want that I return on UITableViewController and I choose a different song the `AVAudioPlayer` will be stopped. I tried many different methods but I get the same error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I also made `AVAudioPlayer` like weak var and I also made `PlayViewController` is a public class but I got the same error. How can I to fix this problem?

```
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "playMusic" {
            var playMVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicVC
            var currentIndPass = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
//            println("array item \(arrayItem)")
            playMVC.currentIndex = currentIndPass
            playMVC.arrayOfSongs = arrayItem
            searchController.active = false
//            println("array item \(arrayItem)")
            //test
            var secondPlayView = PlayFromSearchVC()
            if secondPlayView.audioPlayer.playing == true {
                secondPlayView.audioPlayer.stop()
                println("It is works")
            } else {
                println("It is not works")
            }
            //test
        } else if segue.identifier == "summer" {
//            println("array super filter and count \(arrayFilterOfNames) co \(arrayFilterOfNames.count)")
            var playVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayFromSearchVC
            var currentInt = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
            playVC.currentSongString = arrayFilterOfNames[currentInt]
//            playVC.currentIndex = currentInt
//            playVC.arrayOfSongs = arrayFilterOfNames // arrayFilterNames
            searchController.active = false
            //
            var secondPlayView = PlayFromSearchVC()
            if secondPlayView.audioPlayer.playing == true {
                secondPlayView.audioPlayer.stop()
                println("It is works")
            } else {
                println("It is not works")
            }
            //
        }
    }
```

AVAudioPlayer is

```
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

[image]

Different variant is wrong too
[image]

Comment: change to `if secondPlayView.audioPlayer?.playing`

Comment: @lukya I made it but I got the same error

Comment: remove the `== true` part.. `playing` is a boolean so you need not compare it...

Comment: @lukya I made following if secondPlayView.audioPlayer.playing but I got the same error too.

Comment: @lukya I showed a screen with that variant too.

Comment: Your audioPlayer is not allocated....  `if secondPlayView.audioPlayer?.playing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes no sense:

```
var secondPlayView = PlayFromSearchVC()
if secondPlayView.audioPlayer.playing == true {
```

The first line creates a new instance of PlayFromSearchVC. Since it did not exist before, the second line does not make sense. It's like asking a baby that was just born about it's favorite toy.

You don't show the structure of your `PlayViewController` class. How is `audioPlayer` defined?

Don't use a view controller that can be closed to manage sound play. Create a singleton object that manages sound play. Add a method to the sound manager that stops any sound that is currently playing, and methods to start a new sound playing. Call the sound manager from everywhere that you need to play sounds.

Comment: var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

Comment: Do I need to create a swift file and I create a class which has AVAudioPlayer into it?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Read up on Singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Since the AvAudioPlayer (secondPlayView) is a weak property.It would have gone while PlayViewController is removed from memory.Make sure your AVAudioPlayer instance is initialized properly or referring the same instance when you come back to PlayViewController.

Comment: Not, now the secondPlayView is a var

Answer (score 0):

When you try to set currentTime to AVAudioPlayer item but before you set playing content -> you'll  definitely get such error